# salt file.directoy_exists check in a loop

Tags: salt-stack

Trying to loop over a list of folder to check if the directory exists and then to clean that directory (remove all files).

```
{% set FOLDERS_TO_CLEAN = ['C:\Test\Folder1'] %}
{% for FOLDER in FOLDERS_TO_CLEAN %}
{% if salt['file.directory_exists']({{ FOLDER }}) %}
{{ FOLDER }}_delete:
file.directory:
  - name: {{ FOLDER }}
  - clean: True
  - failhard: True
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problematic line is the third line. With the variable FOLDER that ends up in a syntax error but when i change that to my test string it works. Any idea what i can change so that it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have single quotes around {{ FOLDER }} in the if statement.
Like this:

```
{% set FOLDERS_TO_CLEAN = ['C:\Test\Folder1'] %}
{% for FOLDER in FOLDERS_TO_CLEAN %}
{% if salt['file.directory_exists']('{{ FOLDER }}') %}
{{ FOLDER }}_delete:
file.directory:
  - name: {{ FOLDER }}
  - clean: True
  - failhard: True
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Works! Thanks for the quick help!